# C# removing last line in string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using C# (unity3d).

I have a string containing lines separated by `\r\n`, and I need to remove the last line.
z
I managed to make something work but it takes 3 lines, I feel that maybe there could be something shorter in C# to do that.

Here is my current code :

```
int index = infoTxt.text.LastIndexOf("\r\n");
infoTxt.text = infoTxt.text.Substring(0, index - 2);
infoTxt.text = infoTxt.text.Substring(0, infoTxt.text.LastIndexOf("\r\n")+2);
```

Is this efficient enough to be used often, with a text string growing as time goes on ?
This is for a console-like system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply doing:

```
var trimmed = text.Substring(0, text.LastIndexOf("\r\n"));
```

Tested with:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText("data.txt"); // "row1\r\nrow2\r\nrow3"
var trimmed = text.Substring(0, text.LastIndexOf("\r\n")); // "row1\r\nrow2"
```

---

Your double sub-stringing suggests your data ends with an empty line. If so then you need the [second last index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7751866/6400526) of it:

```
string value = "\r\n";
var text = File.ReadAllText("data.txt"); //"row1\r\nrow2\r\nrow3\r\n"
int lastPosition = text.LastIndexOf(value);
var trimmed = text.Substring(0, text.LastIndexOf(value, lastPosition-1)); // "row1\r\nrow2"
```

*Last - see @serge.karalenka suggestion to use **`Environment.NewLine`** instead of `"\r\n"`*

---

If you have and option of no new lines then you should:

```
var trimmed = text.Substring(0, lastPosition == -1 ? text.Length : 
                  text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine, lastPosition - 1));
```

Comment: This is giving me "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Cannot be negative."

Comment: @FLX which one?

Comment: Second one. You're right there is always an empty line.

Comment: @FLX - that is possible if your text has no new lines. see update

Answer (score 0):

You override the results of the 2nd line with your 3rd line (just adding "\r\n" to it).

Also, you can use Environment.NewLine instead of "\r\n", so your code will be cross-platform.
So just one line will suffice for your task:

```
var trimmed = text.Substring(0, text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```